# Overlapping images in css/html5

Tags: css, html

I am trying to put together a portfolio web site with four images that will be used as buttons and  a center logo.  I want four images to serve as links in the corners of the screen (each taking up roughly half the page) with a center logo overlapping them.

I've put together the CSS for the site, and each time I've tried to preview the site, I get the four images in the corner of the screen, with my center logo not overlapping.

here is the code that I'm using for the images:

```
    div.upperLEFT {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.upperRIGHT {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.lowerLEFT {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    z-index: 10;    
}

div.lowerRIGHT {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.centerLOGO {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

here is my html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

    <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title> CJ Wormely's Portfolio </title>
      <link href = "cjwstyle.css" rel = "stylesheet" type "text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1> CJ Wormely Portfolio </h1>
      <div class = "upperLEFT"> <a href = "about_me/cjwPortfolio_about_me.html"> <img src = "aboutmetile.svg" /> </a></div> 
    <div class = "upperRIGHT"> <a href = "id/cjwPortfolio_ID.html"> <img src = "IDTile.svg"/> </a> </div>
    <div class = "centerLOGO"> <img src = "siteLogo.svg"/> </div>
      <div class = "lowerLEFT"><a href = "mailto:cwormely@bex.net"> <img src = "eMailTile.svg"/></a> </div> 
    <div class = "lowerRIGHT"><a href = "art/cjwPortfolio_art.html"> <img src = "artTile.svg"/> </a></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Share your HTML also. you can create a fiddle for this question.

Comment: Thank you...here is my html:

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to center your logo on the screen.

Now, as the other poster said, your code is "all over the place". I'm thinking you were experimenting and noticed this combination was close to working, and so stuck with it (we've all been guilty of that at some point). But using the right tool for the right job is important (to avoid unpredictable/hilarious results), so might I suggest this combination instead...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CJ Wormely's Portfolio</title>
    <link href="cjwstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>CJ Wormely Portfolio</h1>
    <div class="corner upperLEFT"><a href="about_me/cjwPortfolio_about_me.html"><img src="aboutmetile.svg"></a></div> 
    <div class="corner upperRIGHT"><a href="id/cjwPortfolio_ID.html"><img src="IDTile.svg"></a></div>
    <div class="corner lowerLEFT"><a href="mailto:cwormely@bex.net"><img src="eMailTile.svg"></a></div> 
    <div class="corner lowerRIGHT"><a href="art/cjwPortfolio_art.html"><img src="artTile.svg"></a></div>
    <div class="centerLOGO"><img src="siteLogo.svg"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.upperLEFT {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.upperRIGHT {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.lowerLEFT {
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.lowerRIGHT {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.centerLOGO {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.centerLOGO img {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px; /* your logo height divided in half */
    left: -15px; /* your logo width divided in half */
}
```

There are definitely [several](http://thephuse.com/development/the-best-way-to-vertically-align-in-css/) [different](http://html5hub.com/centering-all-the-directions/) [methods](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) of vertically centering an element. Given the provided info, however, this method should work easily for you.

To see how this is expected to work, please see this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/D2Mz5/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** To use z-index properly in your effect, use     `z-index: 999999;`. Your images are spaced like that, undesirably as your .png because you need to define a wrapper.

Below is what I would do. I would nest in a few `divs` **Note: //** This isn't the full solution, I hope to point you in the right layout direction before writing this full page for you. You will have to define a few more properties to the CSS even to the ones I started - this is the logic I would suggest and should get you there pretty quick.

```
#mainwrap { 
width: 100%;
min-height: ; 
}

#coollogo { 
z-index: 999999;
width: ;
height: ;
position: absolute;
margin-top: ;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#top { 
width: 100%;
height: ;
}

.upperLeft { 
min-width: ;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.upperRight { 
min-width: ;
width: 50%;
float: right;
}

#bottom { 
margin-top: 200px; // define
width: 100%;
height: ;
}
/// etc, etc
```

**The Mark-Up:**

```
<div id="mainwrap"><!-- main wrapper -->

<div id="coollogo"></div><!-- the cool logo -->

<div id="top"><!-- top half -->
<div class="upperLeft"></div>

<div class="upperRight"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom"><!-- bottom half -->
<div class="bottomLeft"></div>

<div class="bottomRight"></div>

</div>
</div><!--// end main wrap -->
```

I would also minimize     `div.upperLEFT {` to just `.upperLEFT {`  as there is no need to type `div` each time. If you continue to run into coding errors, consult a Validator for more information http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Phlume, I think you meant http://www.w3fools.com not .org - but thanks for the link I missed it when it first came back and anything from Paul Irish can't be bad!

Comment: I was using the relative position because I wanted to use the Z index to have my center logo overlapping the corner elements.  I've seen in multiple places that - in order to use z-index, you have to define a position.  I've also seen not to define items with pixels because that will often affect how your site will look on mobile devices.

Comment: I don't have enough of a reputation to put an image of what i would like to achieve up here, so i've placed a link: [link](http://www.wormely.com/what-i-want.png ).  So far, this is what I've been getting [link] (http://wormely.com/what-i-get.png)

Comment: Thank you Secret Agent.  Looking through it now.